# Screen timeout when reading

Tags: 2.2-froyo, screen-timeout, reading

I have my screen timeout set to 30 seconds, which is a good interval normally.
However, when i am in a browser reading or Adobe Reader or ThinkFree or whichever other reader, I would like the timeout to be larger or never.

Is there anyway of doing this in Froyo without manually setting it to 30 mins and after I'm done reading all I wanted to read, set it back to 30 seconds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I use **[Screebl](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keyes.screebl.lite&feature=search_result)** for this. It uses the phones orientation sensors to keep the screen on permanently if it's held at an angle. You can then set the timeout to something very low such as 15 seconds which kicks in when the phone is laid flat.
[image]

Comment: Hadn't heard of that one.  That's the good thing about Android.  If there's a need, someone has tried to fill it.

Answer (score 7):

I use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) for this. You can have separate screen timeouts (and other settings) for individual apps. I bump up the timeout for my ebook readers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a quick way to change this setting while reading, except that some reader apps have a setting which you can turn on which overrides the screen timeout while reading.  I believe Aldiko has this setting, but it's been a while since I've used it.  Not sure of any other reader apps which have it, but it might be a good suggestion to send to the developers of your favorite app.

Comment: Thanks, Blake. I thought there was no real solution for this but I thought I'd ask to make sure.

Comment: Most ebook readers have a "Never Turn screen off" setting.