# Tap screen to turn it back on after timeout

Tags: screen-timeout

I noticed that on my Samsung Galaxy S II (Android 2.3.5) after the display is turned off (per `Settings -> Display -> Screen time-out`) you have to press the physical Home or Power buttons to get it back on. Tapping the screen doesn't do anything.

Obviously the screen should get locked soon, so that you can put the phone in your pocket when the screen is off, but letting you tap the screen immediately after it turns off to wake up the display shouldn't hurt.

Is it just me, or how do you handle this? Is there an app to fix this specific issue? Do you know if this was discussed on the official issue tracker or if it's just my phone/my OS version?

(Aside: I know there are apps that let you configure timeout per-app (see e.g.
[Screen timeout when reading](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4595/screen-timeout-when-reading)), but I'm getting hit by this independent of the app I'm using, and anyway I wouldn't like to have to lock the phone manually to save power when the active app prevents the screen time-out. I think the screen time-out should be based on whether I'm actually using the phone, not on the active app.)

Comment: This is OS and device independent AFAIK, not a bug.  Having a short grace period between screen off and lock makes sense though.  An app like [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keyes.screebl.lite) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I assume that if the screen has truly "turned off" then the touchscreen will simply not work in order to wake it up!? If, however, the screen has dimmed to zero brightness for a period of time _before_ turning off...