# Is there a "Reading mode"?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, screen, screen-timeout

In Andoid 5, when doing nothing, after a few seconds (10 seconds?), the light dims, and after 30 seconds, the screen goes off. (This can be changed in *Settings > Display and wallpaper > Screen timeout*).

This is generally good, but **when reading** something on internet, it's annoying, because the screen goes off all the time, forcing to tap the screen often to keep it on.

**Question: is there an option, easily switchable on/off (for example in the top panel with Wi-Fi, Location, Mute, Screen rotation icons, etc.?) to prevent the screen timeout?**

Note: I've seen a **"Smart stay"** feature ("screen stays on as long as you are looking at it") but this works by *"detecting your face with the front camera so that ..."*.
For both battery and personal reasons, I don't want the camera to be constantly on (watching me ;)) while I'm reading, so I don't want to use "Smart stay" feature.

Note: this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4595/58896) is linked, but it targets Android 2, and is rather old (7 years old), so things might have changed thanks to new Android versions.

Comment: It's a Samsung A3 2015, standard factory ROM.

Comment: If the used app does not support to kep the screen on there are a lot of apps in the store that allows to keep the screen on: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=screen%20awake&c=apps

Comment: I personally use Tasker, which I think is still good enough for your issue